# In c#, is there any reason for having adjacent #'s on the left side of a decimal format?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I was looking at some old code in a team codebase that was doing some decimal formatting like this:

```
exampleDecimal.ToString("###.##")
```

For this example, I don't think the first 2 `#`'s are useful. Since all of the `#`'s before the `.` are optional digits, wouldn't this always give the same result:

```
exampleDecimal.ToString("#.##")
```

However, I read through [this c# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierD), and I wasn't able to conclusively decide whether these 2 formats above were technically identical. Will they always produce the same output, or is there some case I'm missing?

Comment: Should be easy enough to test: `for (decimal i = 0; i < 100000; i+=(decimal)0.01) { Debug.Assert(i.ToString("###.##") == i.ToString("#.##")); }`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks. I just thought there might be some documentation on the behavior somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your cited documentation link:

> The "#" Custom Specifier
>   The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol. [...]
>
> Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed.

So, yes, both format strings will always produce the same results.

Comment: I guess I didn't quite interpret it correctly. Ok, so then anything to the left of a zero before the decimal place would also be redundant. i.e. `"##00.##" == "00.##"`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `#` and `##` produce the same output.

However, when you use multiple `#` symbols, you can embed other characters. For example, a format of `#,###` would produce a number with commas between thousands, if it has enough digits.